# How to monitor the disk space usage of an AWS elasticache redis cluster?

Tags: redis, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticache

This is the reason behind this question: I am using a redis cluster on AWS Elasticcache as a datastore. I do not enable eviction because I need to keep the data alive inside the redis cluster for as long as the users are actively using them.

It is a temporary solution. Eventually I will have a MySQL db to persist the data.

At this stage I want to be able to monitor the disk usage of the Redis cluster.  It is because Redis persists data to disk. I want to ensure any surge of usage does not use up free disk space and cause failure. When the disk usage is above a threshold, I can scale out the Redis cluster.

But based on what I can see in **Cloudwatch -> Metrics**, I do not find any disk usage related metrics.

[image]

Did I miss it? Is there any other way to obtain or infer the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html) that can be used to monitor the disk usage is `BytesUsedForCache`.

Just be aware that this metric can be not available for some Redis engine versions. For example, this metric was available for me in Redis 7 but not available for Redis 5.x.